# Add class only when date found in array

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a calendar with reservation and disable checkboxes(dates) by adding class reserved to check boxes and label  when they already reserved ,

```
$reserved = array(
"2019" => array(
    "3" => array(27 ,28),
    "5" => array(7 ,13)
),
"2020" => array(
    "1" => array(27 ,28),
    "4" => array(7 ,13)
)
);

 // Some code 

 unset($key);
 $key = array_search($day, array_column($reserved, $month2));             
 echo '<label class="container">
         <input id=' . $i . ' type="checkbox">
             <div ' . ((empty($key)) ? 'class="reserved"' : 'class="checkmark"') .' >' 
         . $i .' </div>
     </label>';
}

// Some more code
```

Any ideas ? Full code https://pastebin.com/WCqgSvfb

Comment: With that `$reserved` array setup, it looks like only one day per month can be reserved. Is that what you had in mind, or am I misunderstanding? It seems to me like a month would have an array of days instead of a single value.

Comment: Yes you are right, this is my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comment on your question, I think a month should have an array of days instead of a single value in your `$reserved` array.

```
$reserved = array(
    2019 => array(
        '3' => ['27'],
        '5' => ['28'],
    ), ...
```

If it was like that, you could use this in your loop to check if the current day was reserved:

```
$is_reserved = in_array($day, $reserved[$year][$month]);
```

Comment: Oh, I just noticed you replied to my comment. I think this should work, then.